# Making single executable includes all program file and folders with nsis?

Tags: installation, nsis

I have zip file containing my installation files. I'm extracting this zip and copying these files into installation directory with the script shown below:

```
ZipDLL::extractall "$OUTDIR\demo.zip" "C:\myapp\demo\"
```

if I remove zip file from `$OUTDIR` than installer is not able to find zip file as expected. What I want to do is embedding this zip or its extracted folders into exe itself. I added

```
File -r "$OUTDIR/demo"
```

but this script didn't worked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you use the ZipDll plugin, you are referring to the file you want to process (`demo.zip`) by using its place **at run time**: along the installer.exe.
- When you use the `File` statement to embed some files into the produced installer, you need to refer to the files by using their place **at compile time**.

Replace the `$OUTDIR` in the `File` statement by the path relative to the `.nsi` script.

BTW, you should take the habit to check at the compilation log, NSIS probably tells you about that kind of problem when paths are incorrect at compile-time.